# How can I save RSS feeds permanently to my local PC?

Tags: rss

I have subscribed to a bunch of RSS feeds via Firefox live bookmarks. And every other day, they have completely different set of news items. Is there a way to save today's feeds locally (just the titles, not the entire story)?

This is because with some sites like *[Science Daily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_Daily)*, unlike general news, it's useful to have it all archived.

I have used a couple of RSS feed reader desktop applications. And even they do not seem to have this archiving ability. This way, it'll be a lot like [Google Alerts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Alerts) which sends out an email, and I have the option of retaining it for as long as I want in the inbox.

Comment: Fist of all what operating system are u using? Also what rss feed reader have u already used and why you didn't like them? Every secound rss-reader app has a offline saving feature?

Comment: Am using win 7 ultimate 64 bit OS. Am talking about permanent automatic archival. Just like an email inbox. Have tried using quiterss.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't desktop oriented, and after looking at feature sets of desktop users, which all seemed to depend upon an outside aggregator, I ended up installing my own [Tiny Tiny RSS](http://tt-rss.org/) aggregator on one of my own servers.  It is Linux based.  But you could use VirtualBox to build a local server, and then web browse to it from anywhere. With it, you can mark articles to be archived permanently.  This isn't a straight forward a solution as you might be expecting, but it yields a full fledged RSS aggregator under your own control.

Comment: thanks raymond, but I dont need the entire story archived. Just the headings(http://i.imgur.com/W8HT6Ws.png). But what you are suggesting is a cool way to archive the entire story.

Answer (score 1):

[Awasu](http://www.awasu.com) is a commercial, reasonably-priced, Windows desktop feed aggregator that is highly extensible. Awasu allows you to take action on incoming feed items, saving feed content to databases or files, as soon as it arrives (Channel Hooks) or on a aggregated, periodic basis (Reports). Awasu can also send emails with the feed content.

Comment: thanks kevotheclone, looks like this fits my needs well.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the Importfeed function in Google Sheets: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093337?hl=en

And to store all the stories, you coud look at free desktop solutions like RSS Bandit, RSS Owl or the no more developped but still really good FeedDemon.

If you use a desktop mail reader, you could use Outlook's or Thunderbird's RSS reading feature.

Certainly the best way is to use an online newsreader. Inoreader, even in it's free version stores all the items of your feeds.

But all these solutions store all the content (title ad description)!